# How can I remove the ::after CSS selector which is automaticaly appended to the_content()?

Tags: css

I have a CPT which displays meta values after the_content() in the front end, and this ::after selector is messing with my layout. The selector always appears right after the final element inside the_content().

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It has nothing to do with `the_content()`.

`::after` is a pseudo element that's added with CSS. Note that the `::after` element in the dev tools is only there to help development. It does not exist in the HTML source.

So your theme's CSS must be adding it to whatever element is wrapping `the_content()` in your template. You can remove it by setting `content: none;` on the selector for it. For example, if the element that's wrapping your content is `<div class="entry-content">` then the CSS to remove it could be:

```
.entry-content::after {
    content: none;
}
```

The rules of [specificity](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Specificity) still apply though, so whatever selector you use to remove it needs to be more specific than the one that added it.

Also keep in mind that your theme likely does this for a reason. Most commonly elements like this are used to clear floats and prevent float-aligned content, like images, from breaking outside the parent element.

Comment: Thanks for your answer! The problem was because I added a CSS class for adding a drop-cap to a paragraph in the_content. I am confused as to where the ::after selector was coming from as I did not define it, but content: none; did the trick.